# Pygame display color and resolution distortion between versions

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a game with pygame. One aspect of it forced me to upgrade to pygame2.00dev6, previously I was using pygame 1.9.6. Doing this resolved my initial problem, however created a few new ones. The first problem is I can no longer call the pygame.FULLSCREEN function properly anymore. In the old version, I would use:

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1600, 800), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
```

I am aware the first parameter is redundant if I then call it into fullscreen, however when I didn't fill it (used 0 for both x and y), it didn't give me the correct dimensions of the screen, and without these correct dimensions, much of the game is cut off, as I designed the game not in a ratio of the screen but rather for those dimensions specifically. When running this version of my game I get the following screen:
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OrKe.png)

This is nearly perfect for what I want to accomplish, the sizing is right, the quality is at its max, and the colors are toned correctly. However, when running my code in the new version of pygame, (with the same screen setup code) I am immediately brought with an error:

```
File "/Users/brianmasse/Desktop/python/Games/Teacher Brawl/Teacher_Brawl - third times the charm copy 2.py", line 1729, in map_screen
    pygame.display.flip()
pygame.error: Window surface is invalid, please call SDL_GetWindowSurface() to get a new surface
```

Whenever I update the screen, it shoots me out of the game. I've since discovered that if I set the parameters of the screen initialization to 0 both, then it keeps the window open but the dimensions are askew as well the color and resolution being distorted. See image below:
[Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b88YY.png)

My general question would be how do I properly initialize the screen similar to how I did it in the old pygame, which would be with the correct dimensions, proper color, and sharpness. For additional information, I am running MacOS. 1.15.2, and have not installed SDL additionally, however looking in the package contents of pygame, I see it contains SDL2. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Pygame 2 is still in development, so your best bet is to file an issue over at [github](https://github.com/pygame/pygame), I think. What problem did you have with pygame 1.9.6?

Comment: While using pygame 1.9.6, I wasn’t able to receive any inputs from Xbox controller triggers. I had tried resolving this issue in multiple ways but the only consistent solution I found was to update pygame. Thank you for your help!